# Как дать root пользователю в linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

На моем железе стоит убунта и в ней мой основной пользователь имеет запись в /etc/passwd q0tik:x:1000:1000:q0t,,,:/home/q0tik:/bin/bash (uid & gid по тысяче), что не мешает ему выполнять sudo ... (т.е. как я понимаю он имеет root права). На другом пк я создаю пользователя test и хочу дать ему рута, как советуют советчики надо uid и gid махнуть на нули, но это приводит к тому, что под залогиненом test'ом whoami говорит что это root. Я еще пробовал добавить test в групуу root, тоже безрезультатно, пробовал ставить uid и gid по 1000, пробовал пить святую воду... Как мне дать test'у возможность писать sudo ...

Comment: Думаю, [это](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo) поможет

Comment: *т.е. как я понимаю он имеет root права*, конечно, не имеет. и не надо пытаться их «дать». для запуска процессов от имени другого пользователя используйте прогрмму sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишите visudo, запускаете. Откроется Ваш любимый редектор (скорее всего vim или nano).

Там ищите подходящее место и пишите

```
test ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

сохраняете и выходите. Готово.

Comment: `usermod test -a -G sudo` для debian

Comment: как всегда, в линуксе есть десятки способов сделать "ЭТО"